# Unlocking Bootloader to wipe internal storage

Tags: bootloader

I know that unlocking bootloader does wipe the /data partition. However, can it also wipe the /storage partition and others, too?

Comment: It wipes all data on the internal storage... Data on an SD card setup as portable/external storage is not touched in most cases, it is recommended to remove an SD card prior to unlocking the bootloader just in case though.

Comment: So your answer is: It wipes 100% of the phone?

Comment: Yes, all user data, apps, music, pictures, videos, etc... unless they are stored on an SD card configured as portable storage. It will essentially be as "blank" as the day it came out of the box from the manufacturer, except as noted.

Comment: Then, after unlocking, relocking is possible?

Comment: Nexus, Pixel, or OnePlus... yes... Otherwise it depends on the device, some can and some can't be, but they all have a "flag" of somekind to indicate it was once unlocked. For example, in Moto devices they have a Bootloader Status number, it is 0 when locked, but if relocked becomes 2, and it can not be set back to 0 ever.

Comment: I m not using these: Samsung and/or US carriers, etc. Mine is LG.

Comment: I don't believe LG devices can be "relocked"... but your comment makes me think you don't understand what you are unlocking. Unlocking the bootloader and unlocking the SIM (carrier unlock) are completely different, I have only been referring to bootloader unlock.

Comment: Note: I unlocked the bootloader on my Huawei P8 GRA-UL00, and my user data wasn't wiped. I'm not sure why, but it is possible user data does not get wiped in some instances.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing like storage partition. What you see under /storage/emulated is a [FUSE](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/fuse.txt) implementation of */data/media/userID*. Whenever you unlock or relock the bootloader, fastboot causes [factory reset](https://android.googlesource.com/device/ti/bootloader/uboot/+/master/common/cmd_fastboot.c#1587) of the device which wipes data and cache partitions. No bit of data escapes it, including what you see under */storage*.

[Source](https://android.googlesource.com/device/ti/bootloader/uboot/+/6671d3fe57d47e341530a7c6deb3c8d43bad202e/common/cmd_fastboot.c#1587):

> ```
> printf("oem unlock requested:\n");
> printf("\tUnlocking forces a factory reset and could\n");
> printf("\topen your device up to a world of hurt.  If you\n");
> printf("\tare sure you know what you're doing, then accept\n");
> printf("\tin %d seconds via 'fastboot oem unlock_accept'.\n",
> ```

Comment: Think of it that way: whichever partition accumulated user generated data gets to be wiped. They mostly include data and cache partition under normal circumstances (no deliberate tampering that is).

Comment: When we say *data is wiped* during `oem unlock` can that operation be conceived of as like a `calloc` operation that zeros out that block of memory on the relevant partition? Or is the wiping basically a deletion in the filesystem but the data may still be physically present on the disk where something like the `dd` command could potentially recover it?

Comment: @jxramos implementation of `oem unlock` is vendor specific and is not publicly disclosed, so I don't really know how data wipe takes place.

Answer (score 0):

It wipes the complete storage when the bootloader has never been unlocked. If it has been unlocked it just wipes /data as far as I have experienced this on my oneplus x. (Onyx)

Comment: I m thinking about LG, not 1+. Still I don't have any 1+ phones either.

Comment: @user167294 should be the same, but Im not 100% sure

Comment: `fastboot oem lock`  is only supported on a handful of devices, many devices use a specific process that requires flashing a signed image.

Comment: Ok, I will remove it then.

Comment: What do you mean for "complete storage"?

Comment: Everything the user has modified on the phone. It is like a factory reset